# How can I compare "M" and "Ｍ" (in UTF) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf

I have a situation where I have to search a grid if it contains a certain substring. I have a search bar where the user can type the string. The problem is that the grid contains mix of Japanese text and Unicode characters, 
for example : ＭＡＧシンチ注　３３３ＭＢｑ .

How can I compare for content equality the letter 'M' that I type from the keyboard and the letter "Ｍ" as in the example above? I am trying to do this using plain Javascript and not Jquery or other library. And I have to do this in Internet Explorer.

Thanks,

Comment: Compare for what, it's visual height/width or content equality (match?) or something else?

Comment: Actually it is Content equality to be exact.

Comment: Apply [Unicode normalisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) with the NFKD mode (or NFKC) before comparing the strings. This erases the "fullwidth" property.

Comment: Thanks. But I see that it is not supported in Internet Explorer. Is there an alternative that works on IE ?

Comment: @Rhymoid the `.normalize()` function won't do anything to that string, will it?

Comment: @pointy `'ＭＡＧシンチ注'.normalize('NFKD').slice(0, 3) === 'MAG'; // true`

Comment: OK right, I get it.

Comment: the documentation says no support for IE , are there any alternatives?

Comment: Aside from implementing Unicode normalisation yourself, which is not at all an easy task: no, there is no other way to do this in Internet Explorer. You could opt to have it done by a web server, or tell your user base to stop using Internet Explorer (Microsoft Edge, the successor to IE, does support it), but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a dictionary should work in any browser, find the charCodes at the start of ranges you want to transform then move the characters in your favourite way, for example

```
function shift65248(str) {
    var dict = {}, characters = [],
        character, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { // 0 - 9
        character = String.fromCharCode(65296 + i);
        dict[character] = String.fromCharCode(48 + i);
        characters.push(character);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) { // A - Z
        character = String.fromCharCode(65313 + i);
        dict[character] = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
        characters.push(character);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) { // a - z
        character = String.fromCharCode(65313 + i);
        dict[character] = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
        characters.push(character);
    }
    return str.replace(
        new RegExp(characters.join('|'), 'g'),
        function (m) {return dict[m];}
    );
}

shift65248('ＭＡＧシンチ注　３３３ＭＢｑ'); // "MAGシンチ注　333MBｑ"
```

I tried just moving the whole range `65248..65375` onto `0..127` but it conflicted with the other characters :(

Comment: ok this worked. Only small problem is that it runs those loops for every row  in the grid which might be a little unnecessary memory load I think I can work around that so that it runs only once and later accesses those dictionary directly instead. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in an insightful comment from @Rhymoid on the question, modern JavaScript (ES2015) includes support for *normalization* of Unicode. One mode of normalization is to map "compatible" letterforms from higher code pages down to their most basic representatives in lower code pages (to summarize, it's kind-of involved). The `.normalize("NFKD")` method will map the "M" from the Japanese code page down to the Latin equivalent. Thus

```
"ＭＡＧシンチ注　３３３ＭＢｑ".normalize("NFKD")
```

will give

```
"MAGシンチ注 333MBq"
```

As of late 2016, `.normalize()` isn't supported by IE.

At a lower level, ES2015 also has `.codePointAt()` (mentioned in another good answer), which is like the older `.charCodeAt()` described below but which also understands UTF-16 pairs. However, `.codePointAt()` is (again, late 2016) not supported by Safari.

*below is original answer for older browsers*

You can use the `.charCodeAt()` method to examine the UTF-16 character codes in the string.

```
"M".charCodeAt(0)
```

is 77, while

```
"Ｍ".charCodeAt(0)
```

is 65325.

This approach is complicated by the fact that for some Unicode characters, the UTF-16 representation involves two separate character positions in the JavaScript string. The language does not provide native support for dealing with that, so you have to do it yourself. A character code between 55926 and 57343 (D800 and DFFF hex) indicates the start of a two-character pair. [The UTF-16 Wikipedia page has more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), and there are various other sources.

Comment: `codePointAt` simplifies the handling of the two-character pairs.

Comment: The spec doesn't enforce UTF-16, just 16-bit representation of characters and conformance to ISO/IEC 10646. You may find the environment is actually using UCS-2.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher yes indeed it does. Editing. ALso thinking about getting some coffee :)

Comment: yeah. I think this answer is getting a little close. Now we know the two character looks alike by just observing. How do we tell the browser to do that? How can make 77 and 65325 have same equivalency?

Comment: @RachhekShrestha in general you would have to do the work that the `.normalize()` function does. It's not simple.

Comment: @PaulS. that's true for characters coming from an `<input>` element or something like that, and in that case you've got a more difficult problem. A string constant in JavaScript however will be interpreted as UTF-16 just like anything else in the source text, no?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have access to those strings, by reading the DOM for some other way.

If so, [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) will be your friend.

```js
console.log("Test of values");
console.log("M".codePointAt(0));
console.log("Ｍ".codePointAt(0));
console.log("Determining end of string");

console.log("Ｍ".codePointAt(10));


var str = "ＭＡＧシンチ注　３３３ＭＢｑ .";
var idx = 0;
do {
  point = str.codePointAt(idx);
  idx++;
  console.log(point);
} while(point !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try building your own dictionary and compare function as follows:

```js
var compareDB = {
  'm' : ['Ｍ'],
  'b' : ['Ｂ']
};


function doCompare(inputChar, searchText){
  
   inputCharLower  = inputChar.toLowerCase();
   searchTextLower = searchText.toLowerCase();
   
  if(searchTextLower.indexOf(inputChar) > -1)
       return true;    
    
   if(compareDB[inputCharLower] !== undefined)
    {
      for(i=0; i<compareDB[inputCharLower].length; i++){
        if(searchTextLower.indexOf(compareDB[inputCharLower][i].toLowerCase()) > -1)
          return true;
      }
    }
  
    return false;  
}


console.log("searching with m");
console.log(doCompare('m', "searching text with Ｍ"));

console.log("searching with m");
console.log(doCompare('m', "searching text with Ｂ"));

console.log("searching with B");
console.log(doCompare('B', "searching text with Ｂ"));
```

Comment: This is interesting.

Comment: This is certainly a possibility (though the implementation could be improved), but the number of possible mappings is pretty large.

Comment: Yeah it depends on how many letters you want to map, but basically that is around 26 English alphabet.